# The stream or file "D:\Inetpub.....\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows

I have a website made with Laravel, I need to upload it to windows server (Plesk Cpanel) i have set the database and everything is good, but when trying to open the website it shows me :

```
The stream or file "D:\Inetpub.....\storage\logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

no solution found for windows any help, please?

Comment: give permisison to storage folder and bootstrsap

Comment: in plesk cpanel how?

Comment: i havent used windows servers so .let me check any link which can help you solve

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 1):

You must change permissions for this file, or for all "storage" dir.

I found this in Google for Plesk - [Link for Plesk](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/websites-and-domains/website-content/setting-file-and-directory-access-permissions.70738/) and for Cpanel - [Lunk for CPanel](https://www.plothost.com/kb/change-file-permissions-cpanel-file-manager/).

You must set `777` or `read`, `write`, `execute` permissions for all groups.

Or read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) what permissions you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod 777 path/to/project/storage/logs/laravel.log
```